# Display loader while neural network model is running on backend

Tags: django, asynchronous, neural-network, data-visualization

I am trying to run a neural network model on the backend and want to display results on the front end. I am using django. I am saving graph images into a buffer and then sending them as context to the template page.
I am using the code below

```
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
    buf.seek(0)
    string = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
    uri = urllib.parse.quote(string)
    return render(request, 'graph/index.html', {'data': uri})
```

While running my neural network as it takes some time to produce results, I want to show a loader on the template page.

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to use `django-channels` to tell client to start/stop loader

Comment: i would ask you where you run your DL model ?, are you redfien the django app config, because if you want deacrese time runing you should load your model when django is starting . https://medium.com/saarthi-ai/deploying-a-machine-learning-model-using-django-part-1-6c7de05c8d7v